# Access the function object (closure) of a setter

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, reflection

Assume I have the following class:

```
class Example
{
    function set something(value:String):void
    {
        trace("set something");
    }

    function doSomething():void
    {
        trace("something");
    }
}
```

I can access the functions as objects like this:

```
var example:Example = new Example();
var asdf:Function = example.doSomething;
// this also works - example["doSomething"];

asdf(); // this trace: "something"
```

You do this all the time with events, for example. So, my big question is: Is there any way to get a handle on the setter? Is there some crazy function on Object or somewhere that I don't know about (please say yes :)

I want something like the following

```
var example:Example = new Example();

// the following won't work, because example.something is a string
var asdf:Function = example.something; 
asdf("a value"); // this trace: "something"
```

Comment: Also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478923/referencing-getter-setter-functions-in-actionscript-3

Comment: Dang... I was afraid it was impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `var asdf:Function = example.something;` won't work because compiler treats `example.something` as a getter and returns string (or throws a write-only error if the getter is not implemented).

But since `something` is a property, you can do something like:

```
example["something"] = "a value"; //will trace 'set something'
//or
var property:String = "something";
example[property] = "some value"; //will trace 'set something'
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I want a handle on the function that DOES that. I need to pass it to another class to be called later. You know how you pass function reference to addEventListener so they can be called when the event fires? Like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
class Example{
  function set something(value:String):void{
    trace("set something");
  }

  function doSomething():void{
    trace("something");
  }
}

class AnotherClass{
  function callOtherClassFunction(funcObj:Obj):void{
    if (funcObj.type == "method") {
      funcObj.func.apply();
    }
    else if (funcObj.type == "setter") {
      funcObj.obj[funcObj.func] = "something";
    }
    else if (funcObj.type == "getter") {
      trace(funcObj.obj[funcObj.func]);
    }
  }
}

class Test{
  function Test():void{
    var e:Example = new Example();
    var a:AnotherClass = new AnotherClass();
    a.callOtherClassFunction({obj:e, type:"setter", func:"something"});
    a.callOtherClassFunction({obj:e, type:"method", func:e.doSomething});
  }
}
```